# What is the best format to format a hard-drive to

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, fat32

OK my question is what is the best format for a hard-drive. When I say best a mean:

1. Compatibility with other OS other than windows.
2. Ability for file compression and de-fragmenting.
3. Speed and usability.
4. Resizing and moving the partition.

it can be any thing from NTFS to fat32, just as long as it good for the above things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need NATIVE compatibility or installing drivers is fine ?

Comment: Preferable native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows only supports FAT, exFAT and NTFS.

exFAT is proprietary and rarely usable in other OS, and NTFS (also proprietary) has more features than FAT (compression here from your list).

(by *rarely usable* I mean driver exist but are sometimes unstable as Microsoft doesn't publish the file system's specifications)

So NTFS may not fulfill all your requirements, but it's the one that is the closest to what you want.

If you really want native compatibility on both Windows and Linux, FAT is the only solution, as NTFS driver is rarely installed by default on Linux.

Comment: I would not write off exFAT since MAC supports it, and it is much better than FAT.

As explained on LifeHacker: http://lifehacker.com/5927185/use-the-exfat-file-system-and-never-format-your-external-drive-again

Comment: Indeed, some distributions seem to have drivers, including Ubuntu. It is best suited for Flash drives though, so it may depend on what kind of storage we're talking about

Comment: exFAT also doesn't support Encryption/Compression as filesystem-layer.

Comment: NOTE: FAT32 doesn't support Encryption/Compression at the filesystem layer either.

Answer (score 3):

With recent experiences I'm updating this answer..

FAT32: For small files (under 4GB) FAT32 works on all types of storage media and every major OS but no native encryption/compression support.

NTFS: Address all your 4 requirements. It is supported by NTFS-3g on practically most Linux variants (other have complained of high CPU usage and slower performance. I've noticed it at times but not enough to bother and the convenience far outweighs the complaint). Also [supported on Max OSX](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/)

Both FAT32 and NTFS are resizable and movable, especially if you use [GParted](https://gparted.org/) or [many other resizing tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software).

---

Original answer

There are many formats available. Assuming you want #1 as well as Windows, then definitely NTFS.
The compatibility part of your criteria is the most important. NTFS is readable by other OS's and fits the other 3 criteria you've posted. In some cases you'll have to use a driver but ultimately you'll be able to read it.

The actual answer depends on your list of "Other OS".

Important point is that with drivers you can get more options, but it is best that you first describe what OS choices you want to be compatible to and then determine your format.

Comment: Does this work with Linux

Comment: Depends on distribution, but most of the time, NTFS is not natively compatible. a package install is required, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-fedora-enable-ntfs3g-support/

Comment: Actually, FAT32 has a file system size limit of 2 TB. The 32 GB limit was artificially introduced by Microsoft and *only* concerns the file system creating (aka formatting).